# Faces on mesh look bad and distorted after posing

Tags: faces, weight-painting, topology, pose-mode, distort

I don't like how the faces look when shaded. Is this a topology issue? Weight map issue?

blend file - https://mega.nz/file/OxkBAarC#T0T1koTdttVLV6q5g0XzSmjZfsHM8-gvCFhR8pwT2XI

[image: left side of forearm]
[image: camera view shaded]
[image: bottom face distortion]

Comment: Hello, right click >Shade Smooth?